# base64 encoding issue, java

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I'm using apache library for encoding to base64. But this time problem is very typical. I've a b64 encoded string.

```
MIIHSjCCBjKgAwIBAgIQQuw1emUfNRlPD/euDuzBjDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB"+
"5TELMAkGA1UEBhMCRVMxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEWFjQGFjYWJvZ2FjaWEub3Jn
```

Its the part of certificate (.CER) file. I am just decoding it and again encoding it but result is little bit different. Resultant string is,

"MIIHSjCCBjKgAwIBAgIQQuw1emUfNRlPD/euDuzBjDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA"+                         "/5TELMAkGA1UEBhMCRVMxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEWFjQGFjYWJvZ2FjaWEub3Jn"

The difference is at the end of the first line and starting of the second line. **CB** are replaced by **A/**.

This change invalidates my certificate. Where the problem can be ?

Comment: It would be much easier to say if you add code you use for encode/decode strings.

Comment: First it seemed to be an issue related to UTF-8. For that I tried to read this string in UTF-8, provided it to Base64.encodeBase64() method in UTF-8 also. but then result is completely different.

Comment: `String partOfCer = "MIIHSjCCBjKgAwIBAgIQQuw1emUfNRlPD/euDuzBjDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB"+
"5TELMAkGA1UEBhMCRVMxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEWFjQGFjYWJvZ2FjaWEub3Jn";

byte[] dec1_byte = Base64.decodeBase64(partOfCer);

String dec1 = new String(dec1_byte);

Base64.encodeBase64String(dec1.getBytes()));`

Comment: @RaviAmlani whenever you use `new String(bytes)` always pass encoding as the second parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your intermediate string conversion. If you use only byte array, everything is fine.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String partOfCer = "MIIHSjCCBjKgAwIBAgIQQuw1emUfNRlPD/euDuzBjDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB" + "5TELMAkGA1UEBhMCRVMxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEWFjQGFjYWJvZ2FjaWEub3Jn";
        byte[] dec1_byte = Base64.decodeBase64(partOfCer.getBytes());
//        String dec1 = new String(dec1_byte);
        byte[] newBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(dec1_byte);
        String newStr = new String(newBytes);
        System.out.println(partOfCer);
        System.out.println(newStr);
        System.out.println(partOfCer.equals(newStr));
    }
```

Comment: ok @Zvezdochet it worked...thanks.
But what is the reason why it is not working if I convert bytes to string and then giving string as an input ... ?

Comment: @RaviAmlani You can't make a `String` from an arbitrary byte array (as you are doing with `String dec1 = new String(dec1_byte);`). Class `String` will interpret the bytes as characters, using a character encoding.